# Question regarding the usage of "Bang"

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, construction

Can anyone shed some light on the origin of the use of the word "Bang" to imply a positive adjective?

For example, here are three colloquial phrases which use the word bang to lend strength to the meaning:

> That's a **bang-up** job you've done!
>   That's **bang** out of order!
>   It's **bang** up to date.

Meaning, respectively:

> That's a *really great / the best* job you've done!
>   That's *really* out of order!
>   It's *the most* up to date.

---

*UPDATE*

I've just thought of another one:

> They had him **bang** to rights. (i.e. He was most definitely guilty)

I'm still confused as to where this usage originated. Brian Hooper suggests they could all be a variant of bang-up, which sounds plausible.

It would also appear from the comments that a few of these uses (which I can attest are real and recognisable phrases. Well, in England, at any rate) are unfamiliar to our American friends. So perhaps these are colloquialisms that haven't migrated for some reason, or perhaps they are more modern constructions. I will continue to search.

---

*UPDATE 2*

I've come across some interesting information regarding the origin of the phrase - it appears in one of Dickens' works, Sketches by Boz, where the term Slap-bang is used to refer to a cheap restaurant.

The deal was that both money and food were slapped down on the table because it was a cheap establishment. From this we get the terms slap down and bang down, which seem to have evolved into bang-up and slap-up respectively as their positive opposites. Slap-up seems to be heard only with regard to food (a slap up meal), whereas bang-up seems to have become a more general expression of positivity.

This still doesn't quite satisfy me with regard to the other uses (**bang out of order** and **bang up to date**), but it's a decent start.

Comment: Curious, I've never heard 'bang' used that way. The exclaimation point is often called the 'bang'. You might here, "That's a great job you've done bang", which is just short form for, "That's a great job you've done exclaimation point"

Comment: @Tergiver I second that. Years ago it used to be verbal shorthand for "!" when dictating programming code out loud. (Ironically, in that context it almost always means negation.)

Comment: I've heard the first usage (the idiomatic 'bang up job') quite frequently, but the other two are foreign to me as well.  (American English native)

Comment: I can, although not a native anything-English speaker, corroborate @Dusty's impression.

Comment: I've accepted Guffa's answer as the most comprehensive so far, but have offered up a bounty in case anyone has anything else to offer.

Comment: He shoots from the corner and BANG HE KNOCKS IT DOWN!

Comment: I have the same experience as Dusty; I've only ever heard the first example.  With regard to the "!" symbol, it's commonly called a bang by people who work with computers.  "#!" commonly appears in program code, and it's pronounced "hash bang".  On many servers, there's an orange LED with a silhouette of the ! symbol, and it illuminates if the server has some sort of problem that needs immediate attention.  Computer technicians call it the "bang light".  As for "banged up", that usually denotes being damaged in a violent way, such as a car collision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's slang. A [bang up job](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/definition+of/bang+up+job) is an expression in itself even if it might come from some other use of [bang](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/definition+of/bang). However, bang used that way is usually a positive adjective, not a superlative.

On the other hand, something that is [banged up](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/definition+of/banged+up) is usually broken. You should be careful when to use the expression, as a *bang up job* could easily be mistaken by someone not familiar with both expressions for a job causing something to be banged up, i.e. a lousy job.

It's used both in UK and in the states. Perhaps symptomatically, in the states it seems to be more used for sex, crime and drugs. ;)

Comment: And someone who is banged up is in prison - or pregnant :)

Comment: Thanks for the positive adjective correction - I've amended the question accordingly. However, I'm more interested in how the word bang came to be used in such diverse ways, and I'll continue to look into it. Thanks Guffa for the help :)

Comment: @Andy F: *Bang to rights* seems to come from the older expression *dead to rights* which means "caught red handed", where *dead* in the sense of "absolutely" was replaced by *bang*. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bang_to_rights http://www.word-detective.com/2008/04/11/dead-to-rights/

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory:  It probably derives from its use as an onomatopoeia.  Things that crash make a 'bang' sound and are 'banged up' as a result.  Fireworks used in celebration make a 'bang' sound.  The exclamation mark (!) is referred to as 'bang'.  Gun shots, gavels, and cell doors can all be described as making a 'bang' sound.  Angry people *bang* their fists on a table.

In each of these examples (and the others offered), the action or state being described is one that demands notice and is, therefore, accompanied with some loud remark.